# How to prove if these two random variables are independent or not independent?

Tags: probability-distributions

I came across this question

Let X and Y be independent random variables with distributions.

[image]

Let $Z = XY$

1. Write down a table giving the probability distribution of $Z$
2. Are the random variables $X$ and $Z$ independent?

---

So I managed I already calculated the probability distribution of $Z$ which is:

[image]

The part that I am having difficulty of finding out is if Z and X are independent.

I know that if $P(X \cap Z) = P(X)P(Z)$, then $X$ and $Z$ are independent.

How do I use that to prove that X and Z are independent or not independent?

Any help is truly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be very careful when you say "if $P(X \cap Z) = P(X)P(Z)$, then $X$ and $Z$ are independent". $X$ and $Z$ are random variables so a statement like $P(X)$ doesn't have any meaning.

You can only ask what is the probability of an event. A random variable is not an event. An example of an event is $(X=0)$. So you could ask what is $P(X=0)$? (The answer is $\frac{1}{4}$ from what you have above).

Two events $A$ and $B$ are independent if $P(A \ {\rm and} \ B) = P(A)P(B)$. I'm using "and" because I think it's a bit more intuitive but $\cap$ is also good.

Two (discrete) random variables $X$ and $Z$ are independent if $P(X = a \ {\rm and} \ Z = b) = P(X = a)P(Z = b)$ for all possible values $a$ and $b$.

Although more intuitively you could think about it as "if I knew the value random variable $X$ takes, could that influence my belief of what $Z$ is? If yes, then $X$ and $Z$ are dependent. If no for all values $X$ could take, then they're independent.

Comment: so if I put something like $P(X = 2 and Z = 8)$, how do I calculate it?

Comment: One way: $P(X = 2 \ {\rm and} \ Z = 8) = P(Z=8|X=2) P(X = 2) $ where $P(Z=8|X=2) $ is the probability that $Z=8$ assuming you already know $X=2$. If you already know $X=2$, what value(s) of $Y$ would get you $Z=8$? How likely are you to get those values?

Comment: so is it $\frac{1}{16}$ for $P(Z=8|X=2)$?

Comment: $P(Z=8|X=2) = P(Y=4) = \frac{1}{4}$ since you're given that $X=2$. For conditional probability, you take the conditional part to already be true, you don't factor in how likely it is to happen.

Comment: For example, $P($ I get wet $|$ I'm outside in a hurricane $)$ is very high regardless of how small $P($ I'm outside in a hurricane $)$ is.

Comment: @ohh, I understand now. Thank you for your explanation